# Can't set image in UINavigationBar to the center

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I'm using two images in my navigaton controller. One for the `rightBarButtonItem` and one for the `titleView`. I created both in code. So my problem is that the title view is not in the center, it's a little bit closer to the left side. It's because the right bar button, it's sure, I tested it and found some related questions, but still couldn't solve the problem.

I tried  `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 0.0f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` but doesn't helped me out. I would really appreciate any suggestions.

```
- (void)setupLogo {

    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

    CGRect myImage = CGRectMake(0, 0, 41, 41);
    UIImageView *myLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImage];
    [myLogo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
    myLogo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = myLogo;
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 0.0f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `titleView` is centered between the left and right items. It's not centered on the nav bar.

One possible solution would be to add a dummy left bar button item of the same size as your right bar button item. This will force the `titleView` to the center.